# How to use PRAW in an installed application

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I would like to use PRAW to verify that the **installed application** that I created using https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps will work as expected.

According to
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html an **installed application** can be used and the document links to https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-App-Types#installed-app.

I tried with this:

```
import praw
import logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('prawcore')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='string1',
                 client_secret='string2',
                 redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080',
                 user_agent='string3')

print(reddit.auth.url(['identity'], '...', implicit=True))
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
praw.exceptions.ClientException: implicit can only be set for installed applications
```

Could someone provide me with insight into what I'm doing wrong? 
I need to use the Reddit API to read new posts from a sub-reddit and display them using a list. I don't plan to implement any interaction which requires the user of the app to modify the posts or sub-reddit.

I'm already using PRAW to implement a script (Script Application in https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html) and this works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

(I case others struggle with this. I got a lot of clues by reading https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2 first)

The PRAW API fails to mention that one has to set the client_secret to None when creating the PRAW Reddit instance. This enables the implicit flow. This becomes clear after reading the source of the library.

The following example illustrates the different arguments to the PRAW api needed for the implicit flow and how to obtain the information sent from Reddit to the URI specified using the PRAW Reddit redirect_uri parameter.
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/refresh_token.html#refresh-token

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='client_id',
                 client_secret=None,
                 redirect_uri='http://localhost:port',
                 user_agent='agent')

scopes=['identity', 'read']
state = str(random.randint(0, 65000))
url = reddit.auth.url(scopes, state, "permanent", implicit=True)
```

Setting client_secret to None fixes the client exception mentioned in the question.

The url above will be correct (as in not rejected by Reddit when loaded in a browser) if:
client_id and redirect_uri (and possibly user_agent) matches the values configured using https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps.